# Returning html codes from ajax with .htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, .htaccess

returning html codes from ajax post process

javascript side

```
$('#bgn').live('click',function(){
   var d = {islem:'bugun'};
   $.post('inc/ajax.php',d,function(v){
      $('#sol').text(v);
   });
});
```

php side

```
<?
include "connect.php";
session_start();
if($_POST['islem']=='bugun')
{
  echo 'furkan<br>furkanfurkan<br>furkan<br>furkan<br>furkanfurkan
  <br>furkan<br>furkan<br>furkan';
}
?>
```

dont write into the #sol div "
furkanfurkan"
returned html codes to #sol div
coming data is "...."

why?
if i don't use .htaccess this problem is solved
but i should use .htacess
please help me
sorry for my bad english

thanks for answers, i edit for `var d = {islem:'bugun'};`
i was edited this line but don't solved my problem

this my .htaccess page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^baslik/(.*)/$ baslik.php?id=$1&s=1
RewriteRule ^baslik/(.*)/(.*)$ baslik.php?id=$1&s=$2 
RewriteRule ^kayit$ index.php?islem=yazarol
RewriteRule ^giris$ index.php?islem=giris
RewriteRule ^hakkinda$ index.php?islem=credits
RewriteRule ^istatistik$ index.php?islem=stat
RewriteRule ^mesajlar$ inc/mesaj.php
RewriteRule ^mesajlar/(.*)$ inc/mesaj.php?to=$1
RewriteRule ^yonetim-paneli$ adm.php
RewriteRule ^panel$ inc/panel.php
RewriteRule ^cikis$ index.php?islem=logoff
RewriteRule ^linkolustur/(.*)$ inc/paylas.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^profil/(.*)$ inc/profil.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^entry/(.*)$ inc/entry.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^kimleronline$ inc/online.php
RewriteRule ^nick_to_mail$ index.php?islem=mail_bul
RewriteRule ^yazaramsj/(.*)$ inc/to.php?to=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sozluksau\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sozluksau.com/$1 [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?islem=sayfayok
```

SOLVED :) thanks @dianuj

changed this

first add this line to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^call_my_ajax$ inc/ajax.php
```

and after change this

```
$.post('http://mysite.com/call_my_ajax',d,function(){)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the post value by `$_POST['p']` because you have made your data string to send by `var d = {p:'bugun'};` and getting post variable by `$_POST['islem']` which is wrong

```
<?
include "connect.php";
session_start();
if($_POST['p']=='bugun')
{
  echo 'furkan<br>furkanfurkan<br>furkan<br>furkan<br>furkanfurkan
  <br>furkan<br>furkan<br>furkan';
}
?>
```

And change the `text()` to `html()`

```
 $('#sol').html(v);
```

**Edit**

Change your ajax url to something and add one new rule in `.htaccess`

```
$.post('call_my_ajax',d,function(v){
      $('#sol').text(v);
   });
```

in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^call_my_ajax$ inc/ajax.php
```

Comment: thanks for answer but this don't solved my problem.
my problems's source .htaccess hrefbase because if i don't use .htaccess my codes run with success

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid some of your English is not very clear. But as I understand your code works if you don't have an `.htaccess` file but breaks when you do have this file.

So I would guess your `.htaccess` file is causing the problem. What I would do in your situation is:

1. Install the program **Fiddler2** and get it running (this lets you see the contents of all the requests and responses to your webserver).
2. Try using your website with and without the `.htaccess` file and look at what the responses look like for ajax calls to `.../inc/ajax.php`. I think you might find a helpful error message there.

Comment: i'm trying , downloading  Fiddler2